# Ubuntu One not syncing / wrong time after updates

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-one, sync, time

After latest update of 11.10, Ubuntu One is not syncing anymore, even after resetting the password. The error message is:

> An exception representing an authentication failure.

Also after this update yesterday, the time is one hour too early and cannot be adjusted.

Any idea?

Comment: You're going to need to provide more information about the time issue. Also, where did you see that error message?

Answer (score 1):

Precisely, that error is caused by the time being wrong :-)

I don't know what the reason for the error but it's probably a timezone, DST issue that can be fixed by installing and enabling ntp and updating the system.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks you were right. The time came back to normal by itself and fixed the problem. I guess there was a problem syncing with the server.